# The tangent to the curve f(x) = ln(x^2) at point P(d, f(d)) passes through the point Q(1, -3). What are the coordinates of point P?

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure how to do this question.. I know that the derivative of f(x) = 2/x, and I know that plugging in an x value would give me the tangent of the curve to that point.. but this seems to be going backwards and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your current title formula for $f(x)$, namely $f(x)=\ln(2)$, is probably not right. If it is supposed to be $\ln(2x)$, then the derivative is $\frac{2}{2x}$, that is, $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Also, the derivative that you have calculated is not correct. Remember to use the chain rule

Answer (score 1):

"Plugging in an x-value" won't give you the tangent. It will give you the gradient of the curve at the x-value you plug in.

The question asks you to find the tangent at the point P. This is a straight line of the form $y=mx + c$, where $m$ is the value of the derivative (i.e. the gradient of $f(x)$) at P.

So, in order to answer your question you need to calculate $m$ at P. Once you've done this you will have an equation which contains the unknown number $d$. At this point you need to use the other piece of information you're given, i.e. the tangent goes through the point $Q$, to calculate what $d$ must be.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you're right, apologies for the error. That is what I thought, but if you don't know the coordinates of point P, then how would you calculate the gradient at p?

Comment: @EmmaBlanc: You can calculate it as a function of the unknown number $d$, and later use the fact the line passes through $(1.-3)$ to find $d$. One cannot give a more explicit answer until the actual function in the problem is clarified.

Comment: @EmmaBlanc you do have the coordinates for the point P. It's just that they are in terms of an unknown. Like Andre said: you keep working, with the extra information that you have, and the coordinates become known.